# Is there a way to send email using port 465 only?

Tags: postfix, smtp, openssl

I'm trying to send email via port 465 since my ISP has blocked the port 25.

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect example.com:465
EHLO example.com
AUTH LOGIN sdgfsdgfdgdfg
dfgdfgdf
mail from: myaddress@example.com
rcpt to: myaddress@gmail.com
data
From: Karmo <myaddress@example.com>
To: Karmo <myaddress@gmail.com>
Subject: Email from Postfix

Hi!
.

quit
```

But according to syslog, it still tries to connect to GMail using port 25:

```
Jul 29 21:58:26 vagrant postfix/smtp[30536]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c04::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
```

Is there a way to send an email to GMail or any external server using port 465 only? It has same result when I run it with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if gmail smtp port 465 is reachable from your network, just type in a `telnet alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 465` command. If you don't get an error message back, it is reachable.

There is a possible solution, that you could set up an outgoing mail proxy on another port (f.e. port 24) on some of your servers, if you have, although I don't think it worked in your place (probably you want to use gmail exactly for the same purpose).

The openssl command, which you are calling, is only a tcp port connector. It is practically a telnet client, the only difference that it encrypts data. It hasn't anything to do to your mail logs, even if you are connecting your own postfix with that.

I think, you should set up your postfix to use the gmail port 465 as an outgoing mail server. This can be done by setting the default transport to the `smtps:alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:465` or some similar.